setting onClicklistener to multiple buttons
I'm noob in android developing. I'm writing fitness application's page with trainig excercises. I have many buttons clicking on I want to show popup containing some content different to each button. I have this kode:
val button4day2: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.watch4day2)
        button4day2.setOnClickListener(){
            makePopupDescription(context, R.drawable.pullupsgif,
                context.getString(R.string.pullups_description))
        }

        val button5day2: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.watch5Day2)
        button5day2.setOnClickListener(){
            makePopupDescription(context, R.drawable.triceps_press,
                context.getString(R.string.triceps_press_description))
        }

        val button1day3: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.watch1Day3)
        button1day3.setOnClickListener(){
            makePopupDescription(context, R.drawable.warmupgif,
                context.getString(R.string.warmup_description))
        }

        val button2day3: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.watch2Day3)
        button2day3.setOnClickListener(){
            makePopupDescription(context, R.drawable.squatgif,
                context.getString(R.string.squat_description))
        }

as you see, each button's id differs only two numbers. and for each button I have a certain gif and string to show in popup. So, how can reduce amount of copy-paste in my code?
I thought I can use lists of buttons, gifs and strings. but how to initialise them quickly, not writing every button's id in constructor?
P.S: sorry for my bad English


I thought I can use lists of buttons, gifs and strings.

Yes you can do so, here's an example :
//Buttons array
val buttonIds = arrayOf(
    R.id.watch4day2, R.id.watch5Day2, R.id.watch1Day3, R.id.watch2Day3
)

//Gifs array
val drawableResources = arrayOf(
    R.drawable.pullupsgif, R.drawable.triceps_press, R.drawable.warmupgif, R.drawable.squatgif
)

//StringResources array
val stringResources = arrayOf(
    R.string.pullups_description, R.string.triceps_press_description, R.string.warmup_description, R.string.squat_description
)

Then you need to create a loop to do the setOnClickListener
for (i in buttonIds.indices) {
    val button: Button = view.findViewById(buttonIds[i])
    button.setOnClickListener {
        makePopupDescription(
            context,
            drawableResources[i],
            context.getString(stringResources[i])
        )
    }
}

If you don't like this option you can create a class
data class Exercise(val buttonId: Int, val drawableResId: Int, val stringResId: Int)


Then you initialize the data according your needs
val exercises = listOf(
    Exercise(R.id.watch4day2, R.drawable.pullupsgif, R.string.pullups_description),
    Exercise(R.id.watch5Day2, R.drawable.triceps_press, R.string.triceps_press_description),
    Exercise(R.id.watch1Day3, R.drawable.warmupgif, R.string.warmup_description),
    Exercise(R.id.watch2Day3, R.drawable.squatgif, R.string.squat_description)
)

Then loop through all the exercices
exercises.forEach { exercise ->
    val button: Button = view.findViewById(exercise.buttonId)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        makePopupDescription(
            context,
            exercise.drawableResId,
            context.getString(exercise.stringResId)
        )
    }
}


Thank you very much! Writing a class sounds interesting
